Edit build.prop to download unsupported TV apps on a non-TV device
I am trying to turn an old Samsung Galaxy S8 into a TV box. I want TV apps to be available in Google Play (like YouTube TV), but they are still showing as unsupported even after changing build.prop.
I copied these fields from the Nvidia Shield TV build.prop:

ro.product.model
ro.product.brand
ro.product.name
ro.product.device
ro.product.manufacturer
ro.build.fingerprint
ro.build.characteristics=tv

I cleared Google Play's data and rebooted the phone, but YouTube TV is still shown as unsupported.

I think the device needs to fulfill these requirements to be considered as Android TV (not only software, but also hardware).

That said, probably it's easier to download the APK from 3rd-party sources (e.g. APK Mirror) and try to install it, although the compatibility cannot be guaranteed.

from popular apk repositories, several times i tried to find TV version streaming apps, i never found them, just the mobile versions. So, executed on TV  as portrait mode instead of landscape
